# How do i convert pixel value to double value in c#

Tags: c#

I am getting the size for font as string like "12px" from client side. In Server side, i need assign this value for a property of type double, so i tried to parse the string to double as below.

```
public class MarkerFont
  {

     double size= Convert.ToDouble("12px");
  }
```

But this show, the string is not in correct format, i know the string contains the character, my question is how can i removed the character from the string to take the numbers alone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"12px".Replace("px", "")` ?

Comment: I'm sure in a few minutes, if not seconds, someone will post a code snippet that addresses the specific issue, as the basic issue is easy to solve. But if you would like a good answer that helps improve your understanding of the issue, it would be helpful if you would explain what research you've attempted to solve this on your own, and what part specifically about the information you found it is that you had trouble comprehending.

Comment: Check out this magical link http://tinyurl.com/q87mpe8

Answer (score 3):

You can use String.Replace(from, to), in your case you can use it like this:

```
double size = Convert.ToDouble("12px".Replace("px", ""));
```

If you don't want to use String.Replace() you can also do this:

```
string pixelSize = "12px";
double size = Convert.ToDouble(pixelSize.Remove(pixelSize.Length - 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "12px";
double size= Convert.ToDouble(Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d\.]", ""));
```